# QSS combine ID Selector with sub-controls

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets, qtwidgets

How can I apply a stylesheet to the `groove` and `handle` subcontrolls a `QSlider` with object name `videoSlider`?

Answer (score 0):

This is the order of the selectors:

```css
QSlider#videoSlider::groove:horizontal {
    background: red;
}

QSlider#videoSlider::handle:horizontal {
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 3px;
    width: 10px;
}
```